# springboot multiple module, use @EnableCaching can not be effective in imported module

Tags: spring-boot

[enter image description here][1]There were tow module, module B include some persist code(entity dao service), module A include controller and import module B, the cachemanager config bean was in moudle A, when i run the application that i find @Cacheable annotation on service wasn't work, someone who can help me

code as follow

````java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Resource
    private LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
        RedisSerializer<String> stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        RedisSerializer<Object> jsonString = new FastJsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory);

        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jsonString);

        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jsonString);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * CacheManager
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory factory) {
     
        RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5));
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = config.serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));

        
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = RedisCacheManager
                .builder(RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(factory))
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration)
                .disableCachingNullValues()))
                .transactionAware().build();
        return cacheManager;
    }
}

```java

what should i do


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2NNN.png
````

Comment: Please add some code sample

Comment: A module's package: com.xxx.api,B module's package: com.xxx.persist